# Seeing log output in Python Pyramid unit test

Tags: python, testing, logging, pyramid

I'm not sure if this is an IntelliJ thing or not (using the built-in test runner) but I have a class whose logging output I'd like to appear in the test case that I am running.  I hope the example code is enough scope, if not I can edit to include more.

Basically the `log.info()` call in the `Matching()` class never shows up in my test runner console when running.  Is there something I need to configure on the class that extends `TestCase` ?

Here's the class in **matching.py**:

```
class Matching(object):
"""
The main compliance matching logic.
"""

request_data = None

def __init__(self, matching_request):
    """
    Set matching request information.
    """

    self.request_data = matching_request

def can_matching_run(self):
    raise Exception("Not implemented yet.")

def run_matching(self):
    log.info("Matching started at {0}".format(datetime.now()))
```

Here is the **test**:

```
class MatchingServiceTest(IntegrationTestBase):

def __do_matching(self, client_name, date_range):
    """
    Pull control records from control table, and compare against program generated
    matching data from teh non-control table.

    The ``client_name`` dictates which model to use.  Data is compared within
    a mock ``date_range``.
    """

    from matching import Matching, MatchingRequest

    # Run the actual matching service for client.
    match_request = MatchingRequest(client_name, date_range)
    matcher = Matching(match_request)
    matcher.run_matching()
```

Comment: What is the `log` object ? Is it a `logging.Logger` object?

Comment: usually when you run tests you have to do something to not supress std out. for example with py.test it would be py.test ..... -s

Comment: @ChirilaAlexandru Yes it is a logging.Logger object.  I'm running these tests through IntelliJ's built-in test-runner but I don't see anything specifically suppressing the stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I do not see where you initialize the `log` object but I presume you do that somewhere and you add a Handler to it (`StreamHandler`, `FileHandler` etc.)

This means that during your tests this does not occur. So you would have to that in test. Since you did not post that part of the code, I can't give an exact solution:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger("your-logger-name")
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Although test should generally not have anything printed out to stdout. It's best to use a `FileHandler`, and you should design your tests in such a way that they will fail if something goes wrong. That's the whole point of automated tests. So you won't have to manually inspect the output. If they fail, you can then check the log to see if they contain useful debugging information.

Hope this helps.

Read more on logging [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Comment: This helped.  I am able to see the log output from my service module when running the test.  You are correct, however, that automated testing should not show the output unless there is an error.  It does help me while I am writing the test/code for TDD though as I'm able to see data I would like to see without having to rely on the output __repr__ for everything.  Perhaps I am mistaken, though.